# Quill Link tooltip is invisible by default

Tags: javascript, quill

Today I discovered Quill while looking for a rich text editor, and have tried following the documentation to get it working. So far, most of it works just fine.

My only problem is, that when I click on the Link icon, the tooltip doesn't appear due to the following class being mysteriously added to the ql-tooltip `<div>` element: `ql-out-bottom`.

This class adds the following CSS rule at `quill.snow.css:391`:

```
.ql-snow .ql-out-bottom, .ql-snow .ql-out-top {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This class does **not**  get added in Quill's documentation demo which really perplexes me..

Here's my current setup which is entirely copypastarino'd from the documentation:

```
var snowQuill = new Quill('.quill', {
    placeholder: 'Skriv noget hyggeligt her...',
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
            [{ header: [] }],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link'],
            [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
            [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
            ['clean']
        ]
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

I'm using Quill v1.0.0-beta.11 and grabbing the JS and CSS from cdn.quilljs.com. Hope this post follows all formalities, as I dont post on Stackoverflow often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two classes `.ql-out-bottom` and `.ql-out-top` are added when the tooltip would appear beyond the vertical bounds of the editor.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Well that certainly solves the mystery. Do you know if future development on Quill is going to make it, so that if the Tooltip goes beyond the bounds on one side, that it could perhaps try the other to see if there is space? So for example if a user is typing at the very bottom of the editor and adds a link, then the editor could appear above the highlighted text instead of below (and outside the bounds)? Quill seems like a cool project, and I am aware that it is currently still in Beta.

Answer (score 2):

For those having problems in Angular:

```js
    QuillModule.forRoot({
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: [false, 1, 2] }],
          ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
          ["blockquote"],
          ['link', 'image', 'video'],
          ['clean']
        ],
      },
      bounds: "document.body",
      theme: "snow"
    })
```

The link maybe hidden in Angular, and changing the bounds here does not work because of the way Angular is generated. However, this will fix it:

```html
<quill-editor bounds="self">
```

https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill/issues/145